# Cakephp 3: issue with DomPdf

Tags: php, cakephp, dompdf

I am using CakePHP 3.2 and `dompdf` library. It works well on local system but not on production. My code is the same on both portals. but it's working well with local but not on production.

In my local system, I got this pdf file here is a sample:

[localhost pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J60rj.png)

[production pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMk5d.png)

localhost pdf file got perfectly without font collapse. but after put my code on production it collapses fonts, tables etc.

Please help me. Sorry for my English.

Comment: This can be possible some of the files may be font or css of DOM pdf not loading properly. You should enable and check the php warning on production if not enabled.

Comment: @RohitRasela it's not woking with DOMPdf. I have installed TCPdf and it's working for me.

Comment: TcPdf is also a good library.